# jQuery: A special Argument

Tags: jquery, arguments

I know when I want to pass a property as an argument I can use `[x]` but is it possible to pass

**an argument that consists of two properteis and a `:` in between** ?

```
function boson(w,z){
   $(w).stop().animate({
        z
    },{
        duration:2000
    })


}

    boson(".class","Left:'100%'")
```

I get a syntax error as I leave `z` as it is..

Comment: How about boson(".class",{Left:'100%'});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just pass an entire object?

```
function boson(w,z){
   var defaultProps = {duration:2000};
   var props = $.extend(defaultProps, z);
   $(w).stop().animate(props);
}

boson(".class", {left:'100%'});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/

This way it's easier if you decide to add in multiple properties later, without having to change your entire function :)

Comment: Yeah this is what I have been looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Just visited the page and came across this: *If, however, we want to preserve both of the original objects, we can do so by passing an empty object as the target*.. So shouldn't  `$(w).stop().animate(z);` be  `$(w).stop().animate(props);` or did I get it wrong?  And do I need `{}` to be the first argument of `$.extend` when I pass an empty object as the target?

Comment: @ArchJ Yes you are absolutely right, sorry about the blunder.. Have edited :)

Comment: :) Now something has struck me again.. It came to my mind that the function works this way: `animate({name:value}, {duration:x, etc})` with 2 objects but not 1object: `animate({name:value, duration:x, etc})` [tested: http://jsfiddle.net/MXDPA/ ]... So I edited the solution

Answer (score 0):

what format have you passed into animatie()? the format that pass into animate in {} is always like {name:value}.And "Left:100%" is just a string. that means you just passed a value into it.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to pass the second argument as an object, not a string like you have it there.

`boson( ".class", { "Left" : "100%" } )`